# GWT JavascriptObject ClassCastException in GWT-2.6.1

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

We are working with the Web application which was developed by using GWT and smart gwt project. Currently we are using
GWT-2.5.1 and smart gwt-5.0 in our application.Now we wanted to upgrade our smart gwt upgrade to 6.1 from 5.0 but not changed the GWT.

We got the compilation error with smart-gwt-6.1 with GWT-2.5.0. So we also migrated GWT to 2.6.1. Now we are able to compile our application successfuly.

We have got the runtime exception like below.

```
 public void transformResponse(Object data) { // data contains json string
    JavaScriptObject jsObj = (JavascriptObject) data.// This line causes the below excepton
    }

    ClassCastExcetion: java.lang.Strig can not cast to com.google.gwt.core.cient.Javascript Object.
```

This code was working with the earlier versions of smart-gwt and GWT. but now it is throwing this exception.

Firstly I was not be able to find any documentation about compatability of smart-gwt and gwt.

Could any body tell me how to solve the above issue and how to handle this upgrade of smart gwt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
  public static native JavaScriptObject createObject(String data) /*-{
        return data;
      }-*/;

public void transformResponse(Object data) { 
    JavaScriptObject jsObj = createObject(data.toString());// This line causes the below excepton
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Zakaria, Please mention the full details.

Comment: What do you mean?